# Javascript : transform curl request to ajax call easily?

Tags: javascript, ajax, curl

I'm trying to make ajax calls based on curl requests generated by code I do not have control on. Thus, I'm looking for a simple curl parser in Javascript to generate the corresponding ajax call.

Is there a simple way to do that ?

Otherwise, I'll have to parse the request manually, but that can be tough since the curl requests can be very different.

Comment: Google's Chrome browser has a function like this.  After you execute a call, you can right click it in the Network tab and select "Copy as cURL".  This isn't a script or an automated tool, but it can work in some cases.

Comment: Indeed. But I want to do it the other way around ;) From curl to ajax.

Comment: Oh! oops. My mistake.  Sorry.

Comment: No problem :) I've seen that chromium (don't know about chrome) also has a 'Copy all as HAR' option which is almsot what I'd need. Just need to find how it's done :)

Comment: There are lots of things you can do with `cURL` that you don't have direct control over when sending AJAX requests. Not to mention that AJAX requests are normally restricted to the same domain, while `cURL` is not restricted.

Comment: Mmmh, I mostly need to get the headers, formData, and url. Shouldn't be too much to ask from a good parser ! (edit : and the http verb too of course)

Comment: AFAIK, there's nothing built into JS to do this, so you'll have to code it yourself or search for a library someone else has already written to do it. We're not going to do that search for you -- requests for 3rd-property libraries are off-topic for SO.

Comment: I'm already writing it. Already searched a bit and there seems to be nothing out there matching my needs :(